# Laravel 5 - how to send data to layout views?

Tags: laravel, layout, view, config

I have to send data to layout, which work everytime I open site, which has added layout (not only on mainSite, but on links too ). 
I tried something like this (I added to function boot ):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layout', function($view)
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $view->with('categories', $categories);
    });

}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
```

}

But i have still error :
Undefined variable: categories

```
(View: 
/laravel/shop/resources/views/layout.blade.php) (View: 
/laravel/shop/resources/views/layout.blade.php)
```

How to config it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found my mistake - I forgot to add on the top :
use App\Category;
Subject close.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
view(*)->composer('layout', function($view)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $view->with('categories', $categories)
});

view()->share('categories ', $categories );
```

Answer (score 0):

in the view:

`@extends('some-layout',array('foo' => 'bar'))`

and you can use `$foo` variable in the layout.